# Find reversals in sorted list of words - python

Tags: python, list

Find Reversals

You are given a sorted list of words. Your task is to report all words whose reverse are also in the list, in the order that they appear. Given the list

```
lst = ['art', 'Rat', 'radar', 'scam', 'tar', 'vista']
```

you should report `['rat']`.  You should not report `'tar'`, as we saw `'rat'` first, and already reported that.  Don’t report palindromes.

Write a function

`def find_reversals(lst: List[str]) -> List[str]:`

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet will do that

```
result_list = list()
def find_reversals(lst):
    for word in lst:
        if word[::-1] in lst and word[::-1] not in result_list and word[::-1] != word:
            result_list.append(word)
    return result_list

lst = ['art', 'rat', 'radar', 'scam', 'tar', 'vista']
output = find_reversals(lst)
print(output)
['rat']
```

Comment: I think you should read about functions and how to apply them.